# Find a basis consisting of a union of disjoint cycles of generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, canonical-transformation

$T$ is the linear operator on $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(f(x))=2f(x)-f'(x)$

1) Find a basis for a generalized eigenspace of $T$ consisting of a union of disjoint cycles of generalized eigenvectors

2) Find a Jordan Canonical Form for T

---

Let $\alpha = \{1, x, x^2\}$ be the standard ordered basis

$A= [T]_{\alpha}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   2&-1&0\\
   0&2&-2\\
   0&0&2\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

$det\left(A-\lambda I\right) = \left(2-\lambda\right)^3$.

Thus, $\lambda=2$ and has a multiplicity of $m=3$

I know my dot diagram (one cycle of length 3) and thus was able to find the Jordan Canonical form easily:
$  J=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   2&1&0\\
   0&2&1\\
   0&0&2\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

---

What I need help with is finding the basis for each generalized eigenspace... 
I found the answer in the book: $\beta=\{2,-2x,x^2\}$, but am not sure how to come to that

Answer (score 2):

Since the length of the cycle is $3$, you start with an arbitrary non-zero vector $z_3\in\ker (A - 2I)^3 \setminus \ker (A - 2I)^2$.

The solutions says $z_3 = x^2$ (probably this is the "simplest" one). Then, you must take $z_2 = (A- 2I)z_3$ and $z_1 = (A - 2I)z_2$.

But! It is more important to understand, why this works.

Comment: So, I start by calculating $(A-2I)^3$ and $(A-2I)^2$? And then find a vector that is in the null space of $(A-2I)^3$ but is not in the null space of $(A-2I)^2$? @Antoine

Comment: @NMBL Exactly. However, it would really help you if you understood why this is the way to do it ... Probably, your linear algebra book covers it.